# CMS for internal tools platform

Tags: cms

Looking for recommendations for CMS for an internal platform that will host a variety of infrastructure-related tools (VM creation, DB management, DNS tools, etc.) Think of a scaled-down version of the AWS, Azure or GCP consoles, e.g. a mixture of product documentation and actual UI.

The initial scope of this is quite small, and without anyone involved having significant CMS experience, I'm reluctant to dive into something like Drupal, as I'm concerned that it will turn into "learning Drupal" vs. just getting the MVP produced.

To be clear, the actual tech behind these tools already exists in REST API form, with Terraform integration as well. What we want is way to aggregate docs 
alongside UI to try out the tools via wizards.

Comment: You want to create a webapp that allows users to create VMs, manage databases, set up DNS tools? Or do you already have these tools, and you want to integrate them into a single web interface?

Comment: A CMS is for managing static content, its goal is not to aggregate dynamic tools. What you are looking for is called a "corporate portal".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Maybe a portal is the best route, but my experience with those is that they tend to be for corporate announcements, training, videos, etc. Ours will be half static content (docs, product descriptions) and half custom UI pages to allow users to create resources via the web page instead of API calls (mostly for trial purposes, but that's a separate discussion).

Comment: Are these "*custom UI pages*" embeddable in IFrames? Do these pages need to use the authentication of the visitor?